# Possible Symbolic Integration Bug

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced between 5 and 8 and persisting through 12.0.**

---

I think I may have found a bug, and want to verify is this reproducible in other versions and platforms and not a mistake of mine.

I submit for your consideration that this symbolic integration result is wrong:

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-z^2]/(z - p)^2*z^2/Sqrt[Pi]
 , {z, -Infinity, +Infinity}
 , Assumptions -> Im[p] > 0
 ]
```

> 0

The *Mathematica* result is `0`, and the correct result should be the same as the following command result:

```
D[
 Integrate[
  Exp[-z^2]/(z - p)*z^2/Sqrt[Pi]
  , {z, -Infinity, +Infinity}
  , Assumptions -> Im[p] > 0]
 , p]
```

> ```
> 1 - 2 p^2 - 2 E^-p^2 p Sqrt[Pi] (-I + Erfi[p]) + 
>  2 E^-p^2 p^3 Sqrt[Pi] (-I + Erfi[p])
> ```

For `p = 2 + 2 I`, the problem also exists.

The numerical integration result is correct, which leads me to believe this is a bug.

I think the problem exists with Version 10.0 & 11.1 in Windows.

**Questions:**

**1. Is this a bug present in all platforms?**

**2. Can it be reproduced in other versions of Mathematica?**

Comment: I have removed the `bugs` tag, because it is only to be used if the "bug" is verified by the community (as noted in the `bugs` tag description). I have verified your observations in V10.0.1, but I will leave it to someone else more knowledgeable to decide whether it is a bug or not (I tend to agree that it is).

Comment: The integration seems to agree with your expectation for specific values of `p`.

Comment: If you found a bug, please report it to Wolfram: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/ We are users like you, and can't fix it. Furthermore, this is a questions/answers site, and there is no question in your post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because *it is not a question*. It is a bug report that should have been sent to Wolfram.

Comment: There is precedent on bug "questions" where the only real question is to verify that the bug is reproducible, not a mistake of the user, and compare results to see if present in other platforms and versions. This question can be saved with an edit.

Comment: @rhermans, please do so, if you think this can be saved. Nevertheless, we should rap the OP's knuckles a bit for forgetting that this is a *question*-and-answer site.

Comment: I think the intention counts too.  In this case, the OP has clearly asserted that this is a bug, and came here to *report* it.  I don't see any value in such posts, and *not* reporting it to Wolfram is actually a bad thing.  We do have many posts about bugs, but most of those have a practical problem as a starting point. "I know that this is a bug, but how can I work around it?" "I am not sure that this is a bug, can you help me figure it out before I report it to Wolfram?" "I need to know which versions this bug is present in, to include the appropriate workaround in my published package."

Comment: Ok, I edited the question and reported to Wolfram Technical Support  [CASE:3945664]. Also verified the answer is `0` also in Mma 11.2. Now @J.M. can do the *rap across the knuckles*.

Comment: Yes, the post can always be edited to include *some* question, but if the OP has no real practical problem to solve (that s/he considers potentially solvable), then the question is not appropriate in StackExchange.  If I posted every single bug I found here on SE, most of my questions would be about bugs.  IMO, these kinds of posts should not be encouraged, or soon we'll find people posting here the second they find a new bug.

Comment: There is a reason for the reputation scores, and ♦ status. I submit to your larger experience in the site and will respect any unilateral action from ♦ . I think we were all trying to do the right thing here. *" the intention counts too"*.

Comment: The question was: Can it be reproduced in other versions of Mathematica? I see this bug also in M 8.0.4 (now at hand).

Comment: @rhermans, Thank you very much for helping me edit the problem!

Comment: @innaiz, thank you for that additional data point; I have now been able to add the customary header. FWIW, the evaluation gives a correct result in version 5.

Comment: Persists through v11.3 with macOS 10.13.4